# parse through an array and count

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I have a huge set of arrays like the one below. I want to count how many times a car is shown up under same manufacturersid. How would I do that

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [Make] => Array
                (
                    [ManufacturersName] => Nissan
                    [type] => 4Dr
                    [manufacturersID] => 1
                )

            [Car] => Array
                (
                    [Model] => Mexima

                )


        )
[1] => Array
        (
            [Make] => Array
                (
                    [ManufacturersName] => Nissan
                    [type] => 4Dr
                    [manufacturersID] => 1
                )

            [Car] => Array
                (
                    [Model] => Mexima

                )


        )

[2] => Array
        (
            [Make] => Array
                (
                    [ManufacturersName] => Toyota
                    [type] => 4Dr
                    [manufacturersID] => 2
                )

            [Car] => Array
                (
                    [Model] => Corolla

                )


        )
```

In above sample, Maxima showed up twice in Manufacturerid 1.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the properties of array keys to your advantage here

```
$count_bucket = array();

foreach ($arr as $a) {
    $manufacturer = $a['Make']['Manufacturer_id'];
    $car = $a['Car']['Model'];
    $count_bucket[$manufacturer][$car]++;
}
```

var_dump($count_bucket);

Comment: You may want to add a few checks to see whether the manufacturer array and the car key already exist or not, and add them if needed. Otherwise PHP will complain (softly, but complain nonetheless)